# Выделяется ли запятыми "то есть"?

Tags: пунктуация

"...не разбавляя ее, гуашь(,) то есть, водой" — правильно ли тут стоит запятая после "гуашь"? А то что-то много запятых подряд.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

...не разбавляя ее, гуашь то есть, водой.- Запятая не нужна, трудность вызвала инверсия, если бы было так:"не разбавляя ее, то есть гуашь, водой" - вопрос бы не возник.То есть - пояснительный союз, запятыми не выделяется.

Comment: Довольно распространенная ошибка. Люди часто выделяют запятыми *"то есть"*, думая, наверное, что с ним возможна такая же ситуация, как и с *"вернее"*.

Comment: А что с "вернее"? Там то же самое,без запятой после него:Справочник Лопатина:
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=223  
Запятая ставится только перед этими словами, которые не отделяются от уточняющего члена предложения. Ср.: Приду вечером, точнее в девять часов — вводное слово при уточнении; Приеду осенью, а точнее в октябре — союзное сочетание; Он переутомился, а вернее болен; Отчет о том, каких высот, а точнее глубин удалось добиться в познании природы...(газ.).

Comment: И раз: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_265     
И два: http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach2/

Comment: Но здесь как раз уточняющий оборот, в его начале запятая не ставится.

Comment: А, я Вас поняла. Вернее может выделяться и отдельно как вводное, и в составе оборота.

Comment: Я где-то читал (уже, к сожалению, не могу вспомнить где), что авторы по-разному пишут: некоторые обособляют только *"вернее"*, другие — весь оборот.

Answer (score -1):

нет я думаю не выделяется